# How to set eglot for wasm and go-lang?

Tags: lsp, golang, eglot

I'm just trying to learn Go Language, and WASM with Go-language.

My emacs setup (eglot + [gopls](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/gopls)) works completely fine when I'm working on just go scripts.

However, When I trying to learn `wasm`+`go`, `eglot` is output giving me following error:

```
package main

import (
    "syscall/js"
)
```

Eglot error:

```
main.go 4 error compiler: error while importing syscall/js: build constraints exclude all Go files in /usr/lib/go/src/syscall/js
```

I'm thinking it's because of not setting environmental variable. The `wasm` code compiles with `$ GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o main.wasm`. And eglot doesn't know about `GOOS=js` and `GOARCH=wasm` yet.

How to configure elgot, to make it work wasm and go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, answer to more general question about setting **environmental variable** in emacs is `setenv`. In this case, following worked to me:

- `M-x setenv` and set:

  - `GOOS` to `js`
  - `GOARCH` to `wasm`

All thanks to comment I got on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/zgr9va/comment/izl1a12/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) from u/shassard.